# Where is the grand total column Excel created in my MDX?

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I am having a miserable time trying to recreate part of a pivot table in SSRS. You know when you connect to a cube in Excel, then add measures and other data points, how Excel nicely puts things together for you, including giving you grand totals? Well I am trying to recreate this in SSRS in Query Designer and having no luck. This is day three I'm still stuck on this.

What I can create is all of the dataset along with the proper filters. It's those **grand total** columns that Excel magically created that I can't get. I need those the most for my SSRS report.

Here is the MDX that I currently have. It works great except that in Query Designer in Visual Studio the **grand total** column for "Total Calls" is not appearing.

Does anyone know what to do or how to get that grand total column?

Please help.

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
{ 
    [Measures].[Total Calls], [Measures].[Total Moves] 
} 
ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
{ 
    ([To Person].[Department].[Unit].ALLMEMBERS * [From Person].[Location].[City].ALLMEMBERS * [From Person].[Support].[Person].ALLMEMBERS * [From Person].[ID].[ID].ALLMEMBERS) 
} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, 
MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME 
ON ROWS 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT 
    ( 
        STRTOSET(@MDepartment, CONSTRAINED) 
    ) 
    ON COLUMNS 
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT 
        ( 
            STRTOSET(@Weeks, CONSTRAINED) 
        ) 
    ON COLUMNS 
    FROM [PersonTransf]
    )
) 
WHERE 
( 
    IIF
    ( 
        STRTOSET(@Weeks, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, 
        STRTOSET(@Weeks, CONSTRAINED), 
        [Date].[Sun Weeks].currentmember 
    ), 
    IIF
    ( 
        STRTOSET(@MDepartment, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, 
        STRTOSET(@MDepartment, CONSTRAINED), 
        [From Person].[Department].currentmember 
    ) 
) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, 
BACK_COLOR, 
FORE_COLOR, 
FORMATTED_VALUE, 
FORMAT_STRING, 
FONT_NAME, 
FONT_SIZE, 
FONT_FLAGS
```

Comment: As I pointed in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311144/how-to-create-the-total-column-that-excel-creates-in-mdx) (almost duplicated to this), you have to calculate the total row using SSRS expressions like `SUM(Fields!YourMDXColumn.Value)`which gives you the total sum of the YourMDXColumn column.

Comment: the number will be exactly the same as the number for `[Measures].[Total Calls]`?

Comment: @alejandro zuleta, thank you for your suggestion but your answer is not helping me at all and I'm posting it here again to try and move away from your sum expression suggestion so it does not influence other answers. What excel does to produce the grand total column is a mystery to me right now but it definitely is not summing. The numbers are different from a simple sum. I believe there might be a cross join occurring. But long story short I must do this MDX to get the correct results. So yes I tried your suggestion and it does not work.

Comment: @whytheq, no the numbers will not be the same. The values are higher based on the set of this cube.

Comment: @Zolt, Regardless of what Excel calculates for you, What do you need for the total row, a summing on a column, an average or what? You can do any calculation Excels do in pivot tables from SSRS. In order to help you to achieve that share the data (or sample if you don't want to leave it public) returned from your MDX and the expected results.

Comment: @Zolt we can use the `WITH` clause in `mdx` to create a new measure for you - please can you a table illustrating, with some numbers, what this new column should contain.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a column **outside the group** then just put SUM(Fields!YourMDXColumn.Value) on the cell?

Comment: I tried this and it does not work. It gives me the sum of the row, not the grand total, which is actually different. I need the grand total column from the cube that Excel produces. I'm very familiar with SSRS and know what you are talking about. I've tried your idea even before posting this question. What I really need is the MDX to provide the grand total column.